# Headline of responsive portfolio doesn't behaves correctly

Tags: css, web, responsive-design

Unfortunately the headline always slips if I open the website on smaller devices or resize the browser window:

[danieljwerner.com](https://danieljwerner.com)

The affected part of the code is this here:

```
<div class="header-content">

<?php

require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if ($detect->isMobile() ) {

        echo '<div class="header-content-inner" style="margin-top:-17%;">';

} else {

        echo '<div class="header-content-inner" style="margin-top:17%;">';

}

?>

<h1 id="homeHeading">What will shape the future?<br>Let's find out.</h1>
```

Can anyone give me a hint about this? I don't understand why the browser doesn't calculates the pixels from the percentage correctly...
Thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

The headline slips because of the absolute position set on `header .header-content`. Also, remove the `margin-top` on `.header-content-inner`

Remove this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
header .header-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 0 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, but unfortunately your solution doesn't fix the problem. If I remove the parts that you mentioned, the headline slips like before over my profile picture and over the header bar with the contact information. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you saved your CSS file? Are you sure your CSS reloaded? Provide a screenshot of the issue if so.